# BLE Gatt onCharacteristicChanged method not called

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

We are facing an issue with BLE Gatt onCharacteristicChanged  method. This method is not called.

We have enabled notification using below code:

```
mBluetoothGatt!!.setCharacteristicNotification("NOTIFY_SERVICE_CHARACTERISTIC", true)

val descriptor = NOTIFY_SERVICE_CHARACTERISTIC.getDescriptor(convertFromInteger(0x2902))
descriptor.value = BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE
descriptor.value = BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE
var status = mBluetoothGatt!!.writeDescriptor(descriptor)
```

After this, We are sending code to BLE from onDescriptorWrite Method.

```
{WRITE_SERVICE_CHARACTERISTIC}.setValue({BYTE_ARRAY}) 
val status = mBluetoothGatt!!.writeCharacteristic(RxChar)
```

After sending code to BLE. it will response in onCharacteristicWrite Method. but we are not getting any response in onCharacteristicChanged Method via Notify Service.

Same commands are working in other BLE Scanner Application but my application facing an issue.

Please help us to solve the issue.

Thanks

Comment: Any luck? I have basically the same problem. Example app receives notifications, but my app doesn't, and they are seemingly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the notification settings of the descriptor with the indication setting:

```java
descriptor.value = BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE
descriptor.value = BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE
```

You probably only need notifications and can remove the enabling of indications:

```java
mBluetoothGatt!!.setCharacteristicNotification("NOTIFY_SERVICE_CHARACTERISTIC", true)

val descriptor = NOTIFY_SERVICE_CHARACTERISTIC.getDescriptor(convertFromInteger(0x2902))
descriptor.value = BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE
var status = mBluetoothGatt!!.writeDescriptor(descriptor)
```

If you truly need both notifications and indications you have to set the values like this:

```java
descriptor.value = BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE | BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE
```

The `|` operator does a bitwise OR operation and therefore combines both flags into one

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried both the settings one by one in the code. but did not work this solution for me.
First I have enabled only ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE settings and run the application.
After that, I have enabled only ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE settings and run the application.

Comment: Do you need to enable indications? Does the characteristic support indications?

Comment: @DeepAmin what is the value of `status` after you have written the descriptor

Comment: I am getting status 0 in Write descriptor.

Comment: 0 equals false, that means it is not succesfull

Comment: I think, if the operation succeeds it will return 0 in status.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback#onDescriptorWrite(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattDescriptor,%20int)

Comment: You can implement `onDescriptorWrite` and check the status, but `writeDescriptor` returns a boolean value and 0 = false

Comment: Yes, ```writeDescriptor``` returns true and getting 0 as status in ```onDescriptorWrite``` methods.